# How can embed Form.io in ionic application

Tags: angularjs, forms, ionic-framework, survey, formio

I am trying to create an application using Form io and angular js, facing an issue when included Formio js with angular js.

This is the screenshot of console error:

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: Please, state the exact issue you encountered, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: added image inline

Comment: That is a dependecy injection error. You need the related dependency to be added to your controller or the app: `angular.module('myApp', ['formio']);`

Comment: I have created a survey in form.io, I want to embed that survey in my ionic application(or angular js), Seems some issue when included form.io.js in my ionic application- I think it is due to conflict.

Answer (score 0):

To use Form.io with ionic you have to include the formio library files.

```
bower install --save ng-formio
```

then you have to include it in index.html

```
<script src="lib/ng-formio/dist/formio.js"></script>
```

Finally you have to inject the dependency in your app.

`angular.module('ionicApp', ['formio']);`

Also, you can include the formio css and bootstrap template.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link href="lib/ng-formio/dist/formio.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Is need to install that, I am only included that js and CSS files, is that enough?

Comment: Sometimes in ionic bower install [library] doesn't attach the .js or .css files. But yes, install it via Bower.